# HXT: how to “lift” children of certain elements?

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

Suppose I have this MathML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8”?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi> f </mi> 
    <mo> &ApplyFunction; </mo> 
    <mrow> 
      <mo> ( </mo> 
      <mi> x </mi> 
      <mo> ) </mo> 
    </mrow> 
</math>
```

Suppose I want to “lift” the children of `mi` and `mrow`, I should get (let’s ignore the whitespace change here)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    f
    <mo> &ApplyFunction; </mo> 
    <mo> ( </mo> 
    x
    <mo> ) </mo> 
</math>
```

How should I write that with HXT?

I’m a Haskell newbie... so all I have right now is

```
-- Dealing with command line arguments and stuff…
processRootElement :: IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
processRootElement
    = processTopDown -- What goes here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Quick type rundown

```
XmlTree = NTree XNode
```

meaning that every `XmlTree` has the construction

```
NTree XNode [XMLTree]
```

Where the first argument is the current node, and the second argument is the list of children.

### The creative process

`processTopDown` will take the tree transformation you provide and produce a tree transformation which applies it recursively.

First, let's define the tree transformation you want on a single node:

1. Go through the children of the current node
2. If any match the tags we specify, then

   1. Take all the children of the tag, and
   2. Make them children of the current node instead
   3. Then remove the tag

The transformation doesn't "lift" the children of current node, because that wouldn't be possible on the root.

A good way to do this would be to use `processChildren`, which is an arrow which lets us specify new children for the current node based on the old children. To do this, we'll need to use [conditional arrows](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.16/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowIf.html)

We can then split the design into two parts, a predicate for matching the tags we want, and the transformation we want to perform

#### The predicate

Reminding ourselves of [what forms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.16/docs/Text-XML-HXT-DOM-TypeDefs.html#t:XNode) an `XNode` can take, the one we're interested in is

```
XTag QName XmlTrees
```

We want to match on nodes of this form, for our given tag names. For this, we write a helper function

```
filterOnQName :: QName -> XNode -> Bool
filterOnQName qname (XTag xqname _) 
  | qname == xqname = True
  | otherwise       = False
filterOnQName _ _   = False
```

For ease of use, we want to write the tags as strings, so we'll use `mkName` to convert them into `QName`s. Then our more useful filter function is

```
filterTags :: [String] -> XmlTree -> Bool
filterTags tagNames (NTree xnode _) = any (\qname -> filterOnQName qname xnode) (map mkName tagNames)
```

But this isn't an arrow, which we need it to be for reasons we'll see later. We can simply turn it into one with `isA`

```
childFilter tags = isA (filterTags tags)
```

#### The transformation

We're going two need two arrows for the transformation body - one for when the filter matches, and one for when it doesn't.

For when it doesn't, the transformation is easy - we want to keep the current node.

```
filterFailed = this
```

Here, `this` is the identity arrow - it does nothing.

When the filter matches, we want to get the children - first, let's write a helper

```
getChildren :: XmlTree -> [XmlTree]
getChildren (NTree _ children) = children
```

Handily, because we're working with list arrows, we can turn this straight into an arrow using [arrL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.16/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v:arrL)

```
liftChildren = arrL getChildren
```

#### Combining them

We can now turn this into a single arrow, using `ifA`, the arrow version of `if`

```
liftMatchedChildren tags = ifA (childFilter tags) liftChildren filterFailed
```

And finally, we can describe the transformation we wanted

```
processRootElement
  = processTopDown (processChildren (liftMatchedChildren ["mi", "mrow"]))
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this detailed answer! However, (probably because I did something utterly stupid) when I ran the program, it got stuck and mem usage kept going higher… Here’s my [full program](https://hastebin.com/inonahidiz.sql).

I found that if I change `processTopDown` to `processBottomUp`, the program ran but the result was wrong. Every element would repeat itself once except for `mi` and `mrow` (for example `<mo>a</mo>` becomes `<mo><mo>a</mo></mo>`).

Comment: This looks like a mistake on my part - you want `processChildren` instead of `replaceChildren`. `processBottomUp` is also the way to go.

I'm curious as to why you write `processChildren (processRootElement \`when\` isElem)` - `processRootElement` should be good enough for the transformation you want to apply.

Comment: Indeed it works now! Thank you very much!

The `processChildren` was in an example in the documentation. I basically just copy-pasted it. But now that I have a working program, I’ll see if I can simply it.